# developing costs

Tags: iphone, ios, simulator

do I have to test my app in an iphone in order to be able to upload it? or just ios simulator is enough?

Comment: You must **ALWAYS** test any software you write no matter what platform for, and always on the actual platform!

Comment: if a iphone is too expensive for you, you should buy a second generation ipod touch.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt no, a third or forth generation iPod. 2nd and 1st generation can't run 4.3 (which comes in a few days) so they are pretty useless for developing.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't strictly required to, but you **really** should.

Answer (score 2):

Always, ***always*** test your code on an actual device before submitting it to the app store. Several reasons, including the following two:

1. Less chance of rejection by catching bugs that occur on real devices, as opposed to working fine on the simulator (they happen, and more than you might expect); and
2. Less pissed off users if your app looks or behaves slightly differently than you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You should test it to make sure it runs well. Simulator and device sometimes does behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to test on a iPhone device, but I would strongly recommend it.

Sometimes the Simulator will let a bug slip by while the iPhone will catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides, there are so much you can learn by actually touching the device and test your user interface. Unless you are very imaginative with some experience, finding the right UI solution for touch based device without actually testing it on the device seems unreliable. This is why I always test my app using the actual device, even for the small changes. What you see as appropriate size for a button on the screen can be too small or too big for the user's finger to interact with, for example.